# assign ID value to src in img tag html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

How can I assign a value to the src attribute in the img tag? I retrieved the value of the id from `<span id="image_name"></span>`. Now I want to assign the value in `id` to `src` because it has path of an image.

```js
$('#image_name').text(response[0]['image_name']);
```

```html
<strong>Picture :</strong><span id="image_name"></span>
```

Comment: `$('#image_name').attr('src', response[0]['image_name']);`

Comment: Hey Rayon i have changed it but how to display in html tag

Comment: Thanks man thanks alot

Comment: remove irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append the HTML of the `img` element you want to create to the `#image_name` span. Try this:

```
$('#image_name').html('<img src="' + response[0].image_name + '" />');
```